# Sidekiq worker undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, redis, sidekiq

I'm trying to use Sidekiq with my app, but for some reason I get a `undefined local variable or method "worker" for #<SolutionController:0xb55bc358>`

I have sidekiq, sinatra and slim installed for the Sidekiq web UI, and it doesn't register anything. I do have sidekiq running in another terminal window for now.

Worker call :

```
worker.perform_async(@user)
```

My Worker :

```
# app/workers/worker.rb

    class worker
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    sidekiq_options retry: false

    def perform(s_user)

        user = $client.user_timeline(s_user, exclude_replies: 1,include_rts: 1 ).take(10)
        user.each do |t|
        array_list   = $client.retweeters_of(t.id)
        end
        limited_list = array_list

        array = []
        hash  = {}

        limited_list.each do |g|

            hash = {:key => g.followers_count, :value => g.profile_image_url.to_s}
            array.push(hash)

        end

        array.sort_by! {|h| h[:key]}
        array.reverse!
        final = array.take(10)


    $redis.set("#{hash[:value]}", "#{hash[:value]}")
    end
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a bit more descriptive name, with proper case.  try renaming the class to `MyWorker` , the file to `my_worker.rb` and calling `MyWorker.perform_async(@user)`

Comment: I think this worked since I don't have that error anymore. However, it's showing me some undefined local variable methods in the corresponding view to the page now. 

How can I access the variables made inside the worker now?

Comment: can you provide more information on what you are seeing now?

Comment: Undefined local variable is due to active record class method support async call, but the instance method does not.

For example

user = User.find 1
if you run
user.do_something in the worker

it will say complain because instance method doesn't support async
unless you do user.delay.do_something

Reference: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-extensions